# How to get WLAN / WiFi certificate in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04, certificates

On other operating systems when i connect to the company wifi network it asks me to accept a certificate.

On ubuntu 22.04 network settings pop up with the possibility to choose a certificate from a file. But I don't have this file.
How to get it?

I already tried :

- looking for system-ca-certs=true which is not there. as supposed by
  [Constantly asked for WiFi password and CA certificate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456970/constantly-asked-for-wifi-password-and-ca-certificate)
- looking for phase2-altsubject-matches= as supposed by [WPA2 and EAP cannot connect like other devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723018/wpa2-and-eap-cannot-connect-like-other-devices)

Comment: this should still be valid: https://askubuntu.com/questions/102326/how-install-ca-certificate-for-a-wireless-network

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what caused the issue.

But in Ubuntu 23.10 it works perfect
(I chose no certificate needed)

Hardware HP Elitebook 865 G10